# Xcode 9 beta 5 can't save edited .daes

Tags: scenekit, collada, xcode9-beta

I'm working on a SceneKit project. If I make a superficial edit to a dae (COLLADA file), say editing the scale of a node, Xcode is unable to save it, with the message

"The document "name.dae" could not be saved"

Editing and saving code files works as normal. I've tried this with multiple .daes in different projects, even .daes I've edited with Xcode 8 with no issues before and the problem is identical.

[image: Here's a screenshot of the message in Xcode]

**EDIT: Solved for myself**

I installed Xcode beta 5 on a new machine. On that machine, this problem went away, and so did another one, related to Xcode beta 5 not finding a Framework correctly. I don't have a generalized, reproducible solution here, so I don't think I should be marking this as resolved. Perhaps re-installing Xcode is the solution.

Comment: Is there any information in Console.app ? (look for logs from Xcode). Alternatively, is sharing the dae file possible?

Comment: After I attempt to save, Console Events of this form appear:
    Claim B27A3DF0-236E-4EE5-A42B-BCA838F9B778 granted in client
default 
Claim B27A3DF0-236E-4EE5-A42B-BCA838F9B778 invoked in client
default 
Claim 78D82A38-16AF-49EB-8152-F34D9E7E0E10 granted in client
default 
Claim 78D82A38-16AF-49EB-8152-F34D9E7E0E10 invoked in client
default 
Making presenter C010CD06-025C-4A8E-8B83-00598F9BAD35 observe change
default 
Making presenter C010CD06-025C-4A8E-8B83-00598F9BAD35 observe change

Comment: I believe it's worth filing a bug with that specific Collada file at bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by reinstalling Xcode *megashrug*

Comment: @Mc.Lover, are you asking me how I reinstalled Xcode, or how it fixed my issue? For the latter, I wish, or maybe I don't wish, I knew.

Comment: I am asking about how to fix !